# How to provide API version with DevExtreme ODataStore?

Tags: typescript, odata, devextreme

For a DevExtreme DataGrid in web application written in TypeScript, I specify the following DataSource:

```
new DataSource({
    store: new ODataStore({
        key: 'Id',
        url: 'Employees',
        version: 4
    })
});
```

The server however requires clients to provide an API version through the `api-version` query parameter. So a valid request URL would look like this: `/Employees?api-version=1&$top=10&$skip=0&$count=true`

Should I just append `?api-version` to the `url` property of the ODataStore config or is there a better approach? I could not find any hint in the [ODataStore Documentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/Data_Layer/ODataStore/) or the DevExtreme pages.